# i want implement played video window by xuggle inside A my JPanel?

Tags: java, video, awt, xuggle, xuggler

i can play a video by xuggle , but when i start my program , the video open in it's seperate JFrame !! , i want implement this player inside my own Jframe or JPanel in FullScreen Display Mode , so how can i do this ??

iam using thise code to play the video :

```
private IMediaReader reader;
private IMediaViewer viewer;
viewer = ToolFactory.makeViewer();        
reader = ToolFactory.makeReader("assets/Video/intro_video.flv"); 
reader.addListener(viewer);    
while(reader.readPacket() == null);
```

an also i need know how to load the url by resource method (this.getClass().getResource()) to make this video play and can load the video file when i run the programm from .jar file

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add this code after add listener,
`reader.addListener(ToolFactory.makeViewer(true, JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE));`
If you don't wanna statics screen so make true